# How to expand a sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, user-defined-functions

I want to create a view where all birthdays of all persons are listed. Lets say I want to "expand" a table.

I have a table Person with the attributes ID and Birthday.
I have a function FuncBirthdays that takes an ID and a Birthday and then it lists all birthdays until the current date. For example:

SELECT * FROM FuncBirthdays(123, '01.01.2014');

```
Result:
123; '01.01.2014'
123; '01.01.2015'
123; '01.01.2016'
// Current date is 14.01.2016, so the list stops here.
```

Now I want to create a view with all birthdays of all persons in table Person.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 Person
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT * FROM FuncBirthdays(Person.ID, Person.Birthday)) FB
ON Person.ID = FB.ID
```

The error message in the MS SQL Server 2012 Studio is that Person.ID and Person.Birthday are unbound.

I'm guessing that this way collides with the way JOINS are done. What SQL-concepts could I use to expand a table? Every data set in Person generates a variable amount of data sets in the output. Currently I have solved this problem with a C#.net function that collects the data manually. Is there a pure SQL way?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: You can invoke table-valued functions from the FROM clause using the [APPLY operator].  @DMayuri has provided a great example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The error message in the MS SQL Server 2012 Studio is that Person.ID and Person.Birthday are unbound."

Is because of you are trying to access person in Join result set which can not be accessible. You need to use cross apply in that case, as per my knowledge. Please try following query

```
SELECT * FROM Person p
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM FuncBirthdays(p.ID, p.Birthday)   
) FB
WHERE p.ID = FB.ID
```

Comment: You could shorten this to: *CROSS APPLY FuncBirthdays(p.ID, p.Birthday) AS FB*.

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE1 (ID, Birthday) AS
(
    SELECT * FROM FuncBirthdays(p.ID, p.Birthday)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE1, Person p
WHERE p.ID = CTE1.ID
```

Comment: In the CTE is no reference to the table Person. Its still the problem to connect Person with the Birthday function. But I could replace the function in the DMayuri example with a normal SQL Stmnt.